# How to attach data to columns in existing dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, merge, bind

I'm attempting to import multiple csv files and create a new dataframe that includes specific columns (some with the same name; some different) from each of these files. So far I have been able to create the dataframe with the specific columns I want, but somewhere in my code my data gets lost and doesn't transfer over to each column.

I would also like to create a new column named `status` where I would like to have each cell equal to either `Lost/Gained/Neutral` depending if the same value found in the `all_v.csv` file is also found in the `lost_v` and/or the `gained_v`. If it is found in niether then it is `Neutral`. I attempted to write a line of code for this, but I won't know if it works till I am able to attach the correct data in each column.

**This would give me a total of 8 columns:**
`pre_contact`, `status`, `gained_variation`, `lost_variation`, `coord.lat`, `coord.long`, `country`, `Date`

**Most of these columns come from the 4 files listed below with the exception of the status column:**

`all_v` - `pre_contact`

`status` - `Lost` / `Gained` / `Neutral`

`gained_v` - `gained_variation`

`lost_v` - `lost_variation`

`SOUTH` - `coord.lat`, `coord.long`, `country`, `Date`

**An issue I'm also facing is having disproportionate dataframes. So when I attempt to `merge` or use `rbind`, I get an error saying that my rows do not line up because some columns are larger than others so I would like a way to fix this with adding `NAs`**

Here is my sample code:

```
folder_path<- setwd("/directory/") 
setwd(folder_path)

#this creates a table with two columns: filename and file_path but I'm not sure how to utilize it
all_of_them <- fs::dir_ls(folder_path, pattern="*.csv")
file_names <- tibble(filename = list.files(folder_path))
file.paths <- file_names  %>% mutate(filepath = paste0(folder_path, filename))


#Each file I want to use
gained_v <- read.csv("gained.csv", header = TRUE)
lost_v <- read.csv("lost.csv", header = TRUE)
all_v <- read.csv("all.csv", header = TRUE)
SOUTH <- read.csv("SOUTH.csv", header = TRUE)


files = list.files(pattern="*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
for (i in 1:length(files)){ 
  data <- 
    files %>%
      map_df(~fread(.))
}

# Set Column Names
subset_data <- data.frame(data)
subset_data$status <- with(subset_data, subset_data$pre_contact == subset_data$gained_variation | subset_data$pre_contact == subset_data$lost_variatiion)
subset_data <- subset(subset_data, select = c(pre_contact,status, gained_variation,lost_variatiion,coord.lat,coord.long, country, Date))
subset_data <- as_tibble(subset_data)
write.csv(subset_data, "subset_data.csv")


status_data = read.csv("subset_data.csv", header = TRUE)
status_data <- data.frame(subset(status_data, select = -c(X)))
status_data <- tibble(status_data)
```

So far my output looks like this (where the only data showing is from my `pre-contact` column:

```
pre_contact   status   gained_variation   lost_variation   coord.lat   coord.long   country   Date   
1234           NA     NA       NA                 NA               NA            
6543           NA     NA       NA                 NA               NA
9876           NA     NA       NA                 NA               NA
1233           NA     NA       NA                 NA               NA
1276           NA     NA       NA                 NA               NA
```

Comment: Your first two lines I think should be `setwd("directry")`. `setwd` returns the current directory, which will be assigned to `folder_path` then `setwd(folder_path)` will set the directory to current path, so nothing will change. "directry" is missing 'o' if it should have the full spelling.   
Your code block #this creates a table... doesn't seem used, but could be `library(tibble)` `library(dplyr)` `all_of_them <- dir(pattern="*.csv")` #currently defined but not used. Can use base R.  `file_names <- tibble(filename = all_of_them)`

Comment: The block "# Set Column Names" uses `data` in `subset_data <- data.frame(data)`, but `data` doesn't seem defined. Another potential typo to check: `lost_variatiion`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Isaiah. I accidentally forgot to show my chunk of code that connects with `data` so I added it just now. I also fixed my typos thanks for the heads up. I'm still having issues figuring out what part of my code isn't connecting my data to my dataframe though.